# npm install error ubuntu

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Hi I wanted to install a npm package called nasim-bot but i got an error and couldn't find a solution for it.

The command was:

```
npm install nasim-bot
```

and the error is:

```
> unix-dgram@0.2.3 install /home/ali/Desktop/mailBot/node_modules/unix-dgram 
> node-gyp rebuild
/bin/sh: 1: node: not found
gyp: Call to 'node -e "require('nan')"' returned exit status 127 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:354:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-21-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ali/Desktop/mailBot/node_modules/unix-dgram
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.6
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN install:unix-dgram@0.2.3 unix-dgram@0.2.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:unix-dgram@0.2.3 Exit status 1
npm WARN mailbot@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

Comment: Try to add symlink `node` to `nodejs`

Comment: Like `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/sbin/node`

Comment: tnx my solution is like the solution you told me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was from the node.js that i installed. install it with this commands:

```
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n latest
```

Answer (score 1):

After running command

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

then

```
sudo aptitude install npm
```

solved my problem

Answer (score -1):

check your npm with this command

> sudo npm-check

if an error then re-install npm.

if npm is fine, then there must be some dependencies that would be missing or outdated, mostly outdated cause issues with it.

> npm install -g npm-check-updates

> ncu -u

> npm update

`

Comment: `npm-check` is not provided out of the box in ubuntu, one needs to install this package globally first